# Convert between Blobs and ArrayBuffers without copying?

Tags: javascript, performance, arraybuffer

I can't find any performance info in the documentation about converting between ArrayBuffers and Blobs in Javascript. I believe the standard methods are:

```
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
```

and

```
const resp = new Response(blob)
const ab = await resp.arrayBuffer()
```

Note that I'm only concerned with Blobs that are in-memory, not File-based (so no I/O time is involved.) I did some timings in a codepen: https://codepen.io/oberbrunner/pen/ExjWLWY
which shows that both of those operations scale in time according to the size of the ArrayBuffer, so they are likely copying the data.
In fact just creating a `new Response(blob)` takes longer with a bigger blob, if my timing code is accurate. Also, the new `Blob.arrayBuffer()` function also appears to be O(n), although it's faster than the `Response` way. But not yet well-supported by browsers in 2020.

So my question is: is there authoritative documentation on the expected performance of these operations? Am I just using them wrong? Are there faster (constant-time, zero-copy) ways?

Comment: What part are you requiring to copy the arrayBuffer, if your doing this for the `Reponse` class, it implements the readableStream, so you could use that for streaming your existing arrayBuffer.

Comment: @Keith I'm not sure what you're asking. I'm only creating the `Response` because that's how you get an `ArrayBuffer` from a `Blob`. I want a Blob that represents the whole thing, not just a part. And I want to avoid the time and memory associated with copying the data.

Comment: There is no such thing as "in-memory" `Blob` -- blobs, by definition, are effectively abstract opaque handles to binary data which may be backed by all kinds of mechanisms at the discretion of the user agent. The [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) which defines and specifies `Blob`, doesn't say _anything_ about memory or RAM or something of the kind -- to that end the name "blob" is, perhaps, misleading -- a blob does not imply some blob of data is allocated for a Web page. `ArrayBuffer`, on the other hand...

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of answering an older question, for posterity -- the authoritative documentation you are looking for would be the [relevant sections of] [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dom-blob-arraybuffer) and [ECMAScript-2021](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arraybuffer-objects) specifications for `Blob` and `ArrayBuffer` respectively.

As far as I have been able to determine, neither specification mandates a particular allocation scheme for either class of object; while specification of `ArrayBuffer` by ECMAScript may *appear* to be more suggestive of a particular data allocation mechanism, it's only so within the scope of the specification itself -- I cannot find anything like "you must allocate the data on the heap"; while specification of `Blob` is purposefully even more abstract and vague with regard to where and how data comprising the "blob" is actually allocated if at all.

Most user agents, in part guided by these specifications, will fall somewhere between naively allocating data of corresponding `ArrayBuffer` length, on the heap, while constructed blob objects may be efficiently backed by memory mapped files (in case of `File` blobs, for instance) which will basically make them backed by page file on some operating system -- meaning no RAM reserved at all until so required (for some operation on the blob, like converting it to an `ArrayBuffer`).

So a conversion from a `Blob` to an `ArrayBuffer`, while technically not specified to be `O(n)`, would be so in most user agents, since the latter class facilitates actual immediate read and write data access (by element index etc), while `Blob` does not allow *any immediate data access itself*.

Now, I said "most user agents", because technically you *could* design a very elaborate data access mechanism with so copy-on-write semantics where no data is allocated when obtaining an `ArrayBuffer` from a `Blob` (through any of the methods you described in your question or the more modern APIs like [`Blob`'s `arrayBuffer` method](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dom-blob-arraybuffer)) before the corresponding data needs to be read and/or modified.

In other words, all your benchmarks only pertain to *concrete* implementations (read user agents you have tried) which are free to implement either class and operations related to it however they seem fit as long as they do not violate their corresponding specifications.

However, if enough people will start to employ aggressive conversion of blobs back and forth, there isn't anything stopping vendors like Mozilla or Google from optimizing their implementations into something like described above (copy-on-write) which may or may not make them into `O(log(n))` operations, for instance. After all, JavaScript was for a very long time called "interpreted" language -- but today calling it an interpreted language would be a bit of a misnomer, what with Chrome's V8 and Firefox's SpiderMonkey compiling native code out of it, in the name of optimization. And, again, they are free to do so -- no applicable specification of the language or a related environment mandates it be "interpeted". Same with blobs and array buffers.

Unfortunately, in practice, this means we have to live with what actually runs our programs that use blobs and array buffers -- which incur a real `O(n)` cost when you need to do something useful with a blob, normally.